# Activities overlapping

Tags: android, android-studio, overlap

I am new to writing Android apps, I have been using the internet and Android Studio to create an app for my club as a bit of fun and learn along the way. I have been watching videos, using tutorials and walkthroughs and I am getting to learn the basics.

However, I have got stuck. I used a drawer template from Android Studio and added the activities I needed and buttons on the main screen to the activities and they all worked fine, no overlapping. When I tried to link the drawer icons to the activities, rather than use the buttons on the main screen, they work, but the app (visually) puts the next activities content on top of the one before.

I cant find anything on the internet except something called backstacking, but that is described when the back arrow is used, my problem is to do with selecting an activity from the drawer menu. I have attached a picture to show what I mean. It gets worse the more menu items that are selected.

[image]

If anyone could help, it would be great!

Comment: Please add you code here to understand problem exactly.

Comment: Just check the fragment transaction if you use 'replace' or 'add' getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace()
                .commit();   If you use 'add', make the background of fragments not transparent

Comment: Thank you for all the replies, I sorted it now using view.gone

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XML root layout as a constraint layout maybe your constraints are missing. If you are using constraint layout set both top/bottom and left/right constraint.
If your constraints only top for example it is look good on desing but in device that dont know where to positioning left or right and automatically positioning 0 point to top.

Answer (score 0):

When you click one any one menu item put the visibility of other images as gone like

```
visibility(View.GONE);
```

and the one selected to be visible